# Stop UICollectionView hiding cells out of view bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal-scrolling UICollectionView which is nested in a UIView that is centred and occupies 80% of the screen width.

I want the UICollectionView to be visible screen edge-to-edge rather than constrained to the super UIView bounds.

I have set the following which shows the UICollectionView across the screen width:

`collectionView.clipToBounds = NO`

...but when dragging the collectionView, it hides cells when they are completely outside of the super UIView bounds even though they are partially visible on the screen, which leads to a weird flickering of blank space/cell.

Ideally, I'd like a way to prevent the hiding of the cells completely out of bounds. Is there a way to do this?

The UICollectionView has a maximum size of 3 cells, so I'm not particularly worried about any performance implications of having all cells visible all the time.

Comment: Wouldn't disabling clipping on the superview solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried making the `UICollectionView` occupy 100% of the screen width while setting a content inset that matches your 80% value (something like `collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 375.0 * 0.2, 0.0, 0.0)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is to enlarge the frame of the collection view (and its superview in your case) and add `contentInset`'s to it. You might also want to update `scrollIndicatorInsets`.